# PHP SOAP Client fails via proxy

Tags: php, web-services, soap, proxy, wsdl

I wrote a script about a year or so ago to access a service via the PHP Soap client, and it worked just fine.  The code was not put into production as it was not needed at the time.  Fast forward to a few days ago, and now the same code does not function.  The only change to the system have been updates/upgrades.

I feel it has something to do with the proxy portion of the Soap client.

Here is the code that stopped working (URL replaced with X's):

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient('XXXX?wsdl', array('proxy_host' => self::PROXYHOST, 'proxy_port' => self::PROXYPORT));
```

And the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'XXXX?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "XXXX?wsdl" in...

Now, if I run the same URL as follows via CURL, I get the intended Soap XML response:

```
$mycurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($mycurl, CURLOPT_PROXY, self::PROXYHOST.':'.self::PROXYPORT);
curl_setopt ($mycurl, CURLOPT_URL, 'XXXX?wsdl');
echo curl_exec($mycurl);
curl_close($mycurl);
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="XXXX" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="XXXX" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
     <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="XXXX">
       <s:element name="Login">
          <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
 ....
```

Lastly, if I copy the Soap Client script to a server that does not use a proxy, it works as intended and without issue.

The PHP Version is 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11

I have read through every StackOverflow question I could find that pertained and could not find a resolution.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: the theory about proxy seems right, have you tried another proxy?

Comment: Unfortunately, given the nature of the system, it cannot access another proxy (for security reasons).  That said, the proxy is under our control, and I have other servers, including this one via curl, operating through the proxy just fine.  FYI, the proxy is Squid 3, and as stated, the script worked at one time without issue.

Comment: if the proxy is under your control, why not to create another copy of existing proxy and play with it

Comment: I am not following.. the proxy works great for the several servers behind it, and each is running a different operating systems for different reasons (windows server, ubuntu, etc.) , so why mess with it? I can get the WSDL just fine in the same script using CURL, but it fails when using the SOAP client... do you know where I can find the source for the soap client?  As stated, the script worked just fine a year ago behind this proxy, and now does not.

Comment: I'd recommend using your SOAP client code against test SOAP server directly, then add more variables to the equation, like test proxy, prod proxy, prod endpoints, etc.

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm facing the exact same issue and no idea how to solve it.

Comment: No, I never did find a solution.  I ended up having to open a hole in the firewall to circumvent the proxy and allow a direct connection.